# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1292, "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1970-01-03 00:00:00'")

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando escribir esta query de Update de MySQL en SQLAlchemy, pero estoy teniendo problemas. A ver si alguien puede echarme un cable.

```
UPDATE users SET created = date_add(created, interval 2 day) WHERE id in (26422562);
```

Interpreto que sería algo así:

```
session.query(Users.created).filter(Users.id == 76375).update({'created': ( Users.created + timedelta(days=2))})
```

Pero estoy obteniendo el siguiente error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1292,
> "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1970-01-03 00:00:00'") [SQL:
> UPDATE mydatabase.users SET created=(mydatabase.users.created +
> %(created_1)s) WHERE mydatabase.users.id = %(id_1)s] [parameters:
> {'created_1': datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 3, 0, 0), 'id_1': 76375}]
> (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Gracias de antemano.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Con SQLAlchemy cuando haces un query creas un objeto que puedes manipular en python, entonces puedes hacer algo así:

```
user = session.query(Users).filter(Users.id == 76375)
user.created = user.created + timedelta(days=2)
session.commit()
```